# Space Vector Modulation

Tags: amplifier, pwm, signal

Im looking to learn more about this topic so that I can implement it in an amplifier design. I've read around and understand most of the math behind it, but I'm still a little fuzzy on how to implement it. Here are somethings I would like to know to start with:

- Is this a strictly code-related method generating PWM signals, or is there a way to implement this in hardware?
- Are there certain methods of commutation that do not work with this scheme (such as HEDs, encoders, or resolvers)?

If anyone has any links that would be useful in helping to further understand SVM, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could share them with me.

Comment: I think we might need a bit more information to comment on "Are there certain methods of commutation that do not work with this scheme (such as HEDs, encoders, or resolvers)?" AFAIK the issues vary dependent on the requirements of the system, for example the speed of rotation, whether it is constant speed, torque, impulse response, etc. which is critical.

Comment: those sound more like they are requirements for what type of commutation device you want to use. Not necessarily whether or not a SVM PWM scheme will work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of information at [Texas Instruments InstaSPIN](http://www.ti.com/sitesearch/docs/universalsearch.tsp?searchTerm=instaspin#linkId=1&src=top) including white papers as well as product data and application notes [NB: I do not work for TI and do not benefit from posting this]

There are 5 videos of a Texas Instruments training course at YouTube called ["Teaching Old Motors New Tricks"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpTvZlnrsP0)
IIRC, The first three deal with BLDC motors, and modelling those systems, and the last two, other systems.

They have also uploaded a series of Control Theory videos, but it sounds like you understand that stuff.

It is often possible to do a specific, fixed algorithm in hardware. For example, you could implement using an FPGA.

However, if you watch the TI videos, one of the speakers says that in the 90's, some microcontrollers came with specialised vector space support hardware. However he goes on to say, it was proven in 1996 that centre-aligned PWM provided equivalent benefits, so manufacturers stopped including that specialised hardware.

Now the problem you are considering may be more complex, so I would recommend watching the video, or reading the paper, and deciding for yourself.